# "$\varepsilon$-regular pair" vs. "$\varepsilon$-homogeneous" in Regularity Lemma

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

> **Definition** ($\varepsilon$-regular pair)
>
> Let $G$ be a graph and $U,W\subseteq V(G)$. We call $(U,W)$ an
> $\varepsilon$-***regular pair*** in $G$ if for all $A\subseteq U$ and
> $B\subseteq W$ with $|A|\geq \varepsilon |U|$ and $|B|\geq \varepsilon
>  |W|$, one has  $$|d(A,B)-d(U,W)|\leq \varepsilon.$$

> **Definition** (An alternate definition of regular pairs)
>
> Let $G$ be a graph and $X,Y\subseteq V(G)$. Say that $(X,Y)$ is
> $\varepsilon$-***homogeneous*** if for all $A\subseteq X$ and
> $B\subseteq Y$, one has $$|e(A,B)-|A||B|d(X,Y)|\leq \varepsilon|X||Y| \Leftrightarrow $$ $$|d(A,B)-d(X,Y)|\leq \varepsilon \frac{|X||Y|}{|A||B|}.$$

1. Show that if $(X,Y)$ is $\varepsilon$-regular, then it is $\varepsilon$-homogeneous.
2. Show that if  $(X,Y)$ is $\varepsilon^3$-homogenous, then it is $\varepsilon$-regular.

Part 2 follows easily from definitions but part 1 does not seem so easy. I have some thoughts but they did not work out.

We need to show that $(X,Y)$ is $\varepsilon$-homogeneous, provided that $(X,Y)$ is $\varepsilon$-regular.

Let $A\subseteq X$ and $B\subseteq Y$. I tried to consider the following cases:
i) If $|A|\geq \varepsilon |X|$ and $|B|\geq \varepsilon |Y|$, then the result follows by $\varepsilon$-regularity.

But we can also have the following cases: ii) $|A|\geq \varepsilon |X|,\ |B|< \varepsilon |Y|$; iii) $|A|< \varepsilon |X|,\ |B|\geq \varepsilon |Y|$; iv) ii) $|A|< \varepsilon |X|,\ |B|< \varepsilon |Y|$;

I belive that the remaning 3 cases should be identical to each other. I had some ideas for ii) but they did not work out: if $|B|<\varepsilon |Y|$, then $|Y\setminus B|\geq (1-\varepsilon)|Y|$ and I tried to play with that but ...

I'd be happy to see any ideas which lead to the solution!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $A,B$ we always have the bound $e(A,B)\leqslant |A||B|$. So if $|A|<\varepsilon|X|$ or if $|B|<\varepsilon |Y|$, then $e(A,B)< \varepsilon|X||Y|$. Similarly, in this case, we further have $$|A||B|d(X,Y)<\varepsilon|X||Y|d(X,Y)=\varepsilon e(X,Y)\leqslant\varepsilon |X||Y|.$$ Thus both $e(A,B)$ and $|A||B|d(X,Y)$ are at most $\varepsilon|X||Y|$, and hence (since they are both positive) the absolute value of their difference is also at most $\varepsilon|X||Y|$.

Comment: Wow! Much easier than I thought actually! Nice solution! Thank you! +1

Comment: @ZFR my pleasure, happy it helped! :)

Comment: Just a small remark: you said that $e(A,B)\leq|A||B|$. 1) If $A\cap B=\varnothing$, then it obviously true. 2) But if $A\cap B\neq \varnothing$, then it was not so obvious because there could be edges inside the intersection. However, one can check that $e(A,B)\leq \binom{|A\cap B|}{2}+|A-A\cap B||A\cap B|+|B-A\cap B||A\cap B|+|A-A\cap B||B-A\cap B|=|A||B|-\frac{|A\cap B|^2+|A\cap B|}{2}\leq |A||B|.$ Does it make sense? Thank you!

Comment: @ZFR sorry for the late response on this, I missed your comment! in my opinion you are overcomplicating things. an edge from $A$ to $B$ can be identified with a subset $P\subseteq V(G)$ of size $2$ and such that $P\cap A\neq\varnothing$ and $P\cap B\neq\varnothing$. in particular, every such $P$ is of form $\{a_P,b_P\}$ for some $a_P\in A$ and $b_P\in B$, and now the map sending $P$ to $(a_P,b_P)$ gives an injection from the set of edges from $A$ to $B$ into the cartesian product $A\times B$. in particular $e(A,B)\leqslant |A\times B|=|A||B|$

Comment: I guess there is a small mistake in your reasoning. The map sending $\{a_P,b_P\}$ to $(a_P,b_P)$ is not well-defined. If $A=\{1,2,3\}$ and $B=\{2,3,4\}$, then $\{2,3\}\mapsto (2,3)$ and $\{3,2\}\mapsto (3,2)$ however $\{2,3\}=\{3,2\}$. Does it make sense?

Comment: @ZFR sorry, I think I did not explain clearly enough; for each $P$, we make a *specific* choice of some $a_P\in A\cap P$ and $b_P\in B\cap P$ such that $P=\{a_P,b_P\}$; we can always do this by definition of "being an edge from $A$ to $B$". then the map $P\mapsto (a_P,b_P)$ is well-defined. for example, in your case, when $P=\{2,3\}$, we can either choose $a_P=2,b_P=3$ or $a_P=3,b_P=2$; but once we've made that choice, then $P\mapsto (a_P,b_P)$ is perfectly well-defined

Comment: @ZFR I think the source of your confusion is that this injection from the set of edges between $A$ and $B$ into $A\times B$ is not necessarily *canonical* if $A\cap B\neq\varnothing$. but it still is an injection nonetheless. it might be easier to think about the opposite direction; if there are no edges from $A$ to $B$, then the result clearly true. so assume there is at least one such edge $P_0$. now define a *surjection* from $A\times B$ onto the set of edges between $A$ and $B$ by sending an ordered pair $(a,b)$ to $\{a,b\}$ if $\{a,b\}$ is an edge, and sending it to $P_0$ otherwise

Comment: So you mean the map $P\mapsto (a_P,b_P)$ may not be injection, right?

Comment: @ZFR no, it **is** an injection: if $(a_Q,b_Q)=(a_P,b_P)$ then $Q=\{a_Q,b_Q\}=\{a_P,b_P\}=P$. it is a well-defined injection, I think you are confused because it's not "canonical", and that's why I wrote the alternative argument using a surjection from $A\times B$. but both proofs work just fine; there is no error

Comment: @ZFR does that make sense or is it still unclear to you?

Comment: So but I'm still confused with the well-definedness part. What is wrong with my example?

Comment: I understood the proof with surjection but the proof with injection is a bit confusing.

Comment: @ZFR for every $P$ an edge from $A$ to $B$, make a choice of some $a_P\in A\cap P$ and $b_P\in B\cap P$ such that $P=\{a_P,b_P\}$. for example, in your example, where $P=\{2,3\}$, choose either $a_P=2,b_P=3$ or $a_P=3,b_P=2$; either choice is fine! but you make a single, **fixed** choice for each $P$. now the map in question sends $P$ to $(a_P,b_P)$. this is well-defined! the point is, for some $P$ (like $\{2,3\}$ in your example), there may be multiple valid choices of where to send $P$; but you're just selecting a single one of those choices.

Comment: @ZFR since you understand the surjectivity proof, here's a way of thinking about the injectivity proof that might be helpful. suppose $X,Y$ are sets and that $g:Y\to X$ is a surjection. then can you see how to construct an injection $f:X\to Y$ such that $g(f(x))=x$ for all $x\in X$? there might be many possible choices of such $f$, but you can always construct at least one, and just because there were other possible choices does not mean that $f$ is not well-defined!

Comment: the injection and surjection I'm defining above fit precisely into this framework